# How to optimize loading multiple Google API maps on one page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am bringing in 100 maps to post on the same page, with some markers on each page, and average of 5 markers per map. However when loading the page it takes close to a minute before the google maps load. Here is the code that I have now, I am just not sure of how to get the maps to loader quicker.

```
 window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
                }
          var coords = [
          {lat: 40.88589, lng: -73.892110, zoom: 10}
       ];
    var maps = [];

     var markers = [
       MARKER DATA IN HERE    

     ];

     var counter=100;

    function initialize() {
for(var i = 0, length = counter; i < length; i++)
{
    var point = coords;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

    maps[i] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas' + (i + 1)), {
        zoom: point.zoom,
        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    });       
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();




    for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
        var data = markers[j];
        if(data.Rank==(i+1)){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: maps[i],
            title: data.officer
        });

        //Attach click event to the marker.
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.officer + "</div>");
                infoWindow.open(maps[i], marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
        }
    }

    }
```

}

Comment: My goodness, 100 maps why? No matter what you do, it will be a potential UX nightmare.

Comment: Its a pretty simple page, just one map after the other with the different identifiers.

Comment: How do you intend for a user to navigate or locate a particular map quickly? I am trying to understand this so I can help you.

Comment: So the maps are of landlords and there respective buildings. You would search for a landlords name and then be brought to that part on the page with details on those buildings and the map of that building.

Comment: What about SEO, it would be much better if each map had their own page and descriptive content to match and You can use a Modal to load a map from an external page while staying on one page..

Comment: Well, the page is also for users who are going just to see who is on the list, without having a specific landlord in mind.

Comment: I am worried that you will never be able to load that many, even from Google servers.

Answer (score 1):

If initializing ~100 JavaScript maps is too inefficient / slow, I would try starting with the Static Maps API [1] and loading static images which show the markers but aren't dynamic to give the appearance of your page loading quickly.

Asynchronously, perhaps when you detect the user is getting ready to interact with one of these maps, you could replace the static map with a dynamic JavaScript map.

You could even get more clever and only load the maps which are visible to the user.  If you only see the top 20 maps at a time and the user has to scroll to see the rest, perhaps it only makes sense to load the first ~40 maps so there's content when the user scrolls but you don't waste your time loading 100 maps right off the bat.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro